# Separating the x and y values returned by pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen()

Tags: python, pyautogui

currently I am using python and open cv to return the x and y values of a desired image.

The section of my code related to the question looks like this:

```
pathDesired = os.path.join('C:\\Users', 'matlac', 'Desktop', 'png', 'desired.png')

desiredLocation = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(desiredLocation, confidence=.6)
print(desiredLocation)
```

at the moment, when I print, it returns something like this

```
(898, 423)
```

Is there a way I could create a new variable, and set that to just the numerical y value corresponding to my desiredLocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning a tuple with the x,y coordinates. You've already saved the tuple to the `desiredLocation` variable, so now you just need to access the item. Tuples can be indexed just like lists:

```
desiredLocation = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(desiredLocation, confidence=.6)
x = desiredLocation[0]
y = desiredLocation[1]
```

Python also offers some very elegant syntax when assigning variables from items in a container, you can expand the return value to two variables on the same line:

```
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(desiredLocation, confidence=.6)
```